# How to do a UIPickerView in tvOS?

Tags: uikit, tvos, apple-tv

UIPickerView is not available in tvOS.
How should I build an equivalent to it, knowing that the content of my Pickerview is dynamic and can include up to 10 elements.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Have you tried using a UITableView? (Assuming you don't need multiple columns)

Comment: Yes thanks. I think I will go for a UITableview inside a full screen modal ViewController. I just wandered if there was a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: @nicolasleo Did you come up with an alternative to this?

Comment: Yes, I chose a UIAlertController with multiple UIAlertActions. It looks clean and is very easy to code.

Comment: Open source alternative for tvOS https://github.com/ViacomInc/TVOSPicker